# How to change the pd.Grouper function range?

Tags: python, pandas, python-datetime

I am trying to group a bunch of rows by week - start with any date that is a Monday + the **next six days** (to track project progress). Each week should start on a Monday and should include the number of all project update statuses for that Monday until Sunday.

Right now the following code gives me data for Monday and the *previous* seven days, including the last Monday.

How can I get it to be **forward** looking instead of backward looking?

**DATA SAMPLE:**

```
Date        Status        Proj_ID

2021-09-30  Started       p1
2021-09-30  Started       p3
2021-10-19  Started       p4
2021-10-22  Not Started   p2
2021-10-22  Started       p5
```

My code returns this (it counts backwards from Monday):

```
Week         #
2021-10-04   2
2021-10-11   0
2021-10-18   0
2021-10-25   3
```

I want it to return this (count forwards from Monday):

```
Week         #
2021-09-27   2
2021-10-04   0
2021-10-11   0
2021-10-18   3
```

My code:

```
project_statuses = data.groupby(pd.Grouper(key="Date", freq = "W-MON")).size()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with [resample](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html):

```
df.set_index('Date', inplace=True)
df = df.resample('W-MON', label='left',closed='left').size()
print(df)
```

output:

```
Date
2021-09-27    2
2021-10-04    0
2021-10-11    0
2021-10-18    3
```